# Finding color matrix for Brightness and contrast for iOS Application

Tags: ios, brightness, contrast, colormatrix, colormatrixfilter

I checked out the color matrix for brightness and contrast and I got

```
 {contrast,     0,      0,      0,   brightness
 0,         contrast,   0,      0,   brightness
 0,             0,    contrast, 0,   brightness
 0,             0,      0,      1,     0
 0,             0,      0,      0,     1 }
```

which is a 5*5 matrix.

But in iOS we have only 4*4 matrix for `colorMatrix`

```
CIFilter *colorMatrixFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorMatrix"]; // 2
[colorMatrixFilter setDefaults]; // 3
[colorMatrixFilter setValue:rawImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey]; // 4
[colorMatrixFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:contrast Y:0 Z:0 W:brightness] forKey:@"inputRVector"]; // 5
[colorMatrixFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:contrast Z:0 W:brightness] forKey:@"inputGVector"]; // 6
[colorMatrixFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:0 Z:contrast W:brightness] forKey:@"inputBVector"]; // 7
[colorMatrixFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:0 Z:0 W:1] forKey:@"inputAVector"]; // 8
```

But this doesn't give the desired results, pictures having negative brightness are black.
And same goes for contrast.
Suggest the right matrix for the brightness and contrast for iOS apps